# Finding irreducible fractions between two given fractions in ascending order of denominators and then numerators

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization, fractions

> Time limit per test: 2 seconds
>   Memory limit per test: 512 megabytes
>
> You are given two fractions `a/b` < `c/d` and a positive number `N`.
>   Consider all irreducible fractions `e/f` such that `0 < e, f ≤ N` and
>   `a/b` < `e/f` < `c/d`. Let `s` be a sequence of these fractions
>   sorted in ascending order of denominators and then numerators (fraction
>   `e1/f1` precedes `e2/f2` if either `f1 < f2` or `f1 = f2 and e1 < e2`). You should print first `n` terms of the sequence `s` or the
>   whole sequence `s` if it consists of fewer than `n` terms.
>
> **Input**
>     The first line of each test contains 6 integers `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `N`, `n` (`0 ≤ a ≤ 10^18`, `1 ≤ b, c, d, N ≤ 10^18`, `1 ≤ n ≤ 200 000`, `a/b < c/d`).
>
> **Output**
>     First, print how many terms of sequence `s` you will output. And then output these terms in the right order.
>
> **Examples**
>
> - Input:
>
>   ```
>   0 1 1 1 5 10
>   ```
>
>   Output:
>
>   ```
>   9
>   1 2
>   1 3
>   2 3
>   1 4
>   3 4
>   1 5
>   2 5
>   3 5
>   4 5
>   ```
> - Input:
>
>   ```
>   55 34 68 42 90 1
>   ```
>
>   Output:
>
>   ```
>   1
>   89 55
>   ```
> - Input:
>
>   ```
>   49 33 45 30 50 239
>   ```
>
>   Output:
>
>   ```
>   0
>   ```

So far, I've only managed to write a solution that iterates over all the denominators from `1` to `N`, and for each denominator iterates over all the numerators from `a*f/b` to `c*f/d`, adding all found irreducible fractions to the answer.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

long long a, b, c, d, N, n;
vector<pair<long long, long long>> result;

long long gcd(long long a, long long b) {
    while (b) {
        a %= b;
        swap(a, b);
    }
    return a;
}

void computeResult() {
    for (long long f = 1; f <= N; f++) {
        long long eMax = c*f / d;
        if (c*f % d != 0) eMax++;
        eMax = min(eMax, N);
        for (long long e = a*f / b + 1; e < eMax; e++) {
            if (gcd(e, f) == 1) {
                result.push_back(make_pair(e, f));
                if (result.size() == n)
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> N >> n;  
    computeResult();
    cout << result.size() << endl;
    for (pair<long long, long long> fraction : result)
        cout << fraction.first << " " << fraction.second << endl;
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution is too slow. I wonder how to solve this problem more efficiently.

Comment: I think SO isn't the right platform for this question. If you want a review of your code/algorithm (for efficiency, etc.), [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right platform for it. Please move your question there.

Comment: @AjayDabas I don't want a review of my code/algorithm. I know it's slow. I am looking for another, more efficient solution.

Comment: Could please give the source of this problem? Can a solution be tested online?

Comment: @Evg, unfortunately, there is limited registration.

Comment: When iterating at the end of main, make is `& fraction` to avoid useless copies. Try preallocation space for `result` at the beginning of main too. Oh, and don't use `endl`

Comment: What if instead of calling `gcd(e, f)` you factorize each `f` and then check if `e` is divisible by any of these factors? Or make a mask array like in Eratosthenes sieve. Given the condition `n <= 200 000`, you don't need all the factors up to `10^18`.

Comment: BTW, `result.push_back(make_pair(e, f));` can be simplified to `result.emplace_back(e, f);`.

Comment: @Evg, good suggestions. Unfortunately, if `a = 0`, `b = 10^18`, `c = 1`, `d = 10^18` and `N = 10^18` I will still have to iterate over all `f` from `1` to `N` just to find out that there is no `e` that match any of them.

Comment: But you have a lower bound for `f`: `f_min = d/c`.

Comment: @Evg, I haven't thought about it, `f` lower bound will really help in some cases, but not when `a = 0`, `b = 10^17`, `c = 1`, `d = 10^17` and `N = 10^18`. In this case, I will have to iterate over all `f` from `10^17` to `10^18`.

Comment: But you need only first `200 000` fractions, you don't have to check **all** `f`s in that range. How many `f`s you'll have to check? In this case just one.

Comment: @Evg, it was a bad example of a worst-case. What about `a = 10^18 - 1`, `b = 10^18`, `c = 10^18`, `d = 10^18` and `N = 10^18`?

Comment: We have another lower from the other side, something like `(f-1)/f > a/b` or `f > b/(b-a)`.

Comment: @Evg, I don't quite understand how you can _make a mask array like in Eratosthenes sieve_ faster than in _O(N*logN)_.

Comment: @Bananon, I don't claim it will be faster.

Comment: You know what you want, You know how to code it is as simple as that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting question and I really enjoyed thinking about it, and I don't know why it received so many downvotes. Anyways, the below is my rough sketch of the solution. I will update my answer later if I add some refinement to it.

---

As suggested by [@user3357359 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59723768/4789373), we need a more effective way to generate coprimes. A common technique (that is used in diophantine equation solvers) is [Farey Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

> **Definition:** a Farey Sequence of order `n` between `a/b` and `c/d` is the ascending (by value) sequence of irreducible fractions `p/q` such that `a/b <= p/q <= c/d`, where `q < n`.

Properties of Farey Sequence is presented in [this paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/fareyproject.pdf).
So, we have several questions at hand:

- **How to effectively generate Farey Sequence of order `n`?**
  Knowing the first element `a0/b0 = a/b` and the second element `a1/b1`, one can generate `a2/b2` using the following algorithm (with complexity `O(1)`):

  ```
  k = int((n + b0) / b1)
  a2 = k * a1 - a0
  b2 = k * b1 - b0
  ```
- **How to get the second element of Farey Sequence of order `n`?**
  We know that the denominator is somewhere in the range `1..n`. We also know that `a/b` and `c/d` are neighbors in Farey Sequence if and only if `b*c - a*d = 1`. So by itering the value of `d` through `1..n` we can find the smallest fraction, which will the the next one in the sequence. Complexity `O(n)`.
- **How do we decide which order of Farey Sequence we should generate?**
  Blindly generating of order `N`, when `N` is in magnitude of `10^18` is stupid. Moreover, you won't have enough memory for that. We only need to generate a Farey Sequence of some order `k`, such that the length of it is larger than `n` which is bounded by `200000`. This is the hardest part of this algorithm, and right now the tools in number theory only allows us to estimate: `|F_k| = 3*k^2 / pi^2`. So we have:

  ```
  k = ceil(sqrt(n * pi^2)) + C
  ```

  In [page 11 of this paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/fareyproject.pdf) you can also find the approximation error of this formula, so that you accomodate more room for error, thus the `C`. Note that, for each `a/b` and `c/d`, the length of `F_k` would be different.

To sum up, the pseudocode for the algorithm is:

```
1. Estimate the order k of the Farey Sequence to generate, such that |F_k| >= n
2. Calculate the second element of F_k. O(k), where k << n and 1 < n < 200000
3. Generate the whole Farey Sequence. O(n), where 1 < n < 200000
4. Sort by the requirements. O(n log n), where 1 < n < 200000
```

In the worst case scenario when your estimation in `step 1` gave less elements than `n`, you'll need to generate again, using a bit higher order `k'`. Which will only increase the execution time of your algorithm by a constant. So, the overall complexity is `O(n log n)` in average, where `n < 200000`.

---

**Remarks:** the bottleneck of this algorithm is estimation of order `k`. This might be avoided completely by using not Farey Sequence, but the [Stern-Brocot Tree](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Stern.shtml). The tree generates exactly in the order that you need, but I doubt that in an arbitrary setting with `a/b != 0/1` and `c/d != 1/1` it will iterate through all the fractions in a good order.

Comment: Just realized how to specify the algorithm more and make the sequence order deterministic, with overall complexity `O((log n + log N) * n)`. Will update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: The Stern-Brocot Tree is also fine. It should work, as it generates the same values as Farey Sequence, just in different order.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over all denominators from 1 to N, but you don't need to iterate  over all numerators in the given range.

For any irreducible fraction *numerator/denominator*, *numerator* and *denominator* are [coprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers). So what you need is to efficiently generate all coprimes of *denominator* for which *co-prime/denominator* lie in the given range.

For example, for denominator = 8, coprimes are 1,3,5,7. The irreducible fractions in the range [0,1] are 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8. You can expand this range of irreducible fractions by adding a integer to them: 1+1/8, 1+3/8, 1+5/8, 1+7/8 => 9/8, 11/8, 13/8, 15/8 are the irreducible fractions with 8 as denominator in the range [0+1,1+1] = > [1,2]

Pseudo-code for generating all coprimes of x such that a/b < coprime/x < c/d :

```
prime_factors_of_x = get_prime_factors(x)
is_coprime = boolean array of size x
set every element of is_coprime to True
// next, set to False all elements indexed by multiples of a prime factor of x
for every factor in prime_factors_of_x:
   // next loop can be a vectorial operation in some languages
   for i in 0..(x/factor):
      is_coprime[i*factor] = False

all_coprime_list = [] // empty list
min_coprime = floor(a/b * x)+1
max_coprime = floor(c/d * x)-1
for i in min_coprime..max_coprime:
   if is_coprime[i mod x]:
      all_coprimes_list.append(i)
```

This is the overall idea.

Comment: And how can I _efficiently generate all coprimes of denominator for which co-prime/denominator lie in the given range_?

Comment: @Bananon, I hope my pseudo-code is helpful. I would write it in C++ if I could. I am a python guy.

Comment: Thanks for this optimization idea. I'll upvote your answer. But I want to note that your algorithm will be more efficient than checking `gcd(x, i)` for each `i` in `min_coprime..max_coprime` only if `max_coprime - min_coprime` is relatively large. So I suggest dynamically choosing one of our algorithms depending on the values of `x` and `max_coprime - min_coprime`. Unfortunately, this optimization still won't be enough to pass at least `a, b, c, d, N ≤ 10^9, n ≤ 1000` group of tests.

Comment: In my python tests, once you can do that inner loop as a vectorial operation, this algo is way faster. It become virtually linear. In python/numpy, we write `is_coprime[::factor] = [False]*len(is_coprime[::factor])` . In the first solution, there is a call to GCD in a nested loop, which seems quadratic complexity.
Anyway, to further improve it, I would cache some computation results.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other problem, you will notice that it sort works if `N=10^9`, but if `N=10^18` then your code will have overflow when multiplying by f, and everything will fall apart. You can do `long long eMax = (long long)(((long double)c) * f / d);`
(and similarly for lower bound) to reduce that problem, but it will slow it down.